# Regex uppercase for 2 character only

Tags: regex

I've got the below which is for a Git push rule, it works fine with the below example:

```
^(fix|feature|wip|dev-task|release)\/([a-zA-Z]+)\-\d+\-(\w+\-*)*


feature/ab-1234-fix
```

How can enforce uppercase letters ONLY for the AB? This will only ever be 2 characters.

```
feature/AB-1234-fix
```

Comment: `[A-Z]`, so remove lowercase(`[a-z]`)?

Comment: If you are sure there's always 2 Characters you can use `[A-Z]{2}` in your second capture group, instead of +, then you restrict it to only be 2 characters.

Comment: It must be something like `^(fix|feature|wip|dev-task|release)\/(AB|(?!(?:ab|aB|Ab)-)[a-zA-Z]+)-\d+-(\w+-*)*`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
^(fix|feature|wip|dev-task|release)\/(AB|a[^b]|[^a]b|[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{3,})\-\d+\-(\w+\-*)*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ObJ6eZ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fix                      'fix'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    feature                  'feature'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    wip                      'wip'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    dev-task                 'dev-task'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    release                  'release'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AB                       'AB'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a                        'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^b]                     any character except: 'b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^a]                     any character except: 'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    b                        'b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]{3,}             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (at least 3 times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \-                       '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \-                       '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \-*                      '-' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of \3 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \3)
```